# What's the Idiomatic way for using custom api client across react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

My frontend application contains the ApiClient class which hides details about http communication with my server.
That's simple TypeScript class with an axios client as private field.

I faced with doubt about initializing client at root component and passing it to some children.

At this moment I initiate my client in the root component as simple js field from constructor:

```js
constructor() {
  super()
  ... // init state here 

  ... // some initializations like this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)

  this.apiClient = new ApiClient()
}
```

Some children components depend on `apiClient` too (e.g. login component should send request to the login endpoint, editModal component sends request for updating entity by id).
Now I'm passing apiClient as props:

```js
<Login show={this.state.show}
                       handleModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
                       handleSuccessfulLogin={this.handleSuccessfulLogin}
                       httpClient={this.apiClient}
                /> }
...

<EditModal
                    httpClient={this.apiClient}
                    ...
                />
```

What is the idiomatic way for passing it to the component? Is it correct to pass the client as props?
If I understand react documentation correctly, props and state are used for rendering, and that's a bit confusing for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your api client doesn't depend on any props/state from the components, the best way is to initialise it separately and then just import in the file where you need to use it:

```
// apiClient.js

export const apiClient = new ApiClient();

// component.js 

import {apiClient} from '../apiClient';
```

If you need to handle login/logout inside component, which sets the token inside the api client, you can add `login` and `logout` methods, which would be called after the client is initialised. Since you have only one instance of the client inside your app, these changes (login and logout) will have effect inside all the components that use the client:

```
// Client.js
class ApiClient {
  constructor() {
    // do intance init stuff if needed
    this.token = null;
  }

  login(token) {
    this.token = token;
  }

  logout() {
    this.token = null;
  }
}


// apiClient.js

export const apiClient = new ApiClient();

// component.js 

import { apiClient } from '../apiClient';

const LoginPage = props => {

  const handleLogin = () => {
    const token = // get the token

      apiClient.login(token);
  }
}


// anotherComponent.js
const User = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiClient.getUser()
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: My ApiClient has private field `token: string | null` which contains an jwt token.
In my toy app I'm trying to handle login / logout actions and set token field with string on login and with `null` on logout. 
That's a dependency between a client and component and the reason why I try to place it in component. Is this a bad idea and mixing of responsibilities?
Should I just pass token as a parameter of every api method?

Comment: Please clarify your implementation of the api class. It is confusing whether we should be using hooks or classes for this. I would prefer a class - unless react recommends otherwise i.e. as above